# Devolver lista de cadenas con longitud mayor o igual a 5 caracteres

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucle-for, condiciones

Tengo la siguiente lista llamada: names ["David", "John", "Annabelle", "Johnathan", "Veronica"], como bien dice el título, necesito generar una nueva lista con los nombres que tenga 5 o más caracteres, tengo el siguiente código:

```
for i in names:
    if len(i) > 5:
        listas = [i]
        print (listas + i)
```

No sé donde o como colocar la instrucción para que genere e imprima la lista nueva, ya que como está ahí en el código genera una lista por cada nombre por separado y si coloco print por fuera del bucle solo imprime el último nombre.

Comment: Antes del for pon listas=[] y reemplaza la línea siguiente a if por listas.append(i). El print lo sacas fuera del for y solo es necesario print(listas). Si es nombre de 5 a más letras tu condición debe se >= 5

Comment: `print(*[name for name in names if len(name) >= 5], sep='\n')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, deseas aplicar un filtrado a una lista de cadenas, obteniendo como resultado una nueva lista de cadenas cuyas cadenas posean una longitud mayor o igual que 5.

---

Para lograr esto, apliqué unos ajustes al código que expones, tal que así:

```
new_names = []

for name in names:
    if len(name) >= 5:
        new_names.append(name)
    
print(new_names)
```

Se trata de emplear el método [`append`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/python-lista-append-como-agregar-elementos-a-una-lista-explicado-con-ejemplos/) para agregar un elemento al final de una lista en Python.

Además, debes declarar tu lista de destino antes del `for` y el `print` fuera de este como se muestra en el ejemplo anterior.

---

Quisiera proponer además, un par de implementaciones alternativas para lograr esto:

**for if de una línea:**

```
def filter_names(names):
    return [name for name in names if len(name) >= 5]
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
names = ["David", "John", "Annabelle", "Johnathan", "Veronica"]

print(filter_names(names))
```

**Expresión lambda:**

```
def filter_by(names, operator):
    return [name for name in names if operator(name)]
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
names = ["David", "John", "Annabelle", "Johnathan", "Veronica"]

print(filter_by(names, lambda name : len(name) >= 5))
```

Answer (score -1):

f = list(filter(lambda x:len(x)>5,names))
print(f)

Comment: `[x for x in lista if len(x) > 5]` hace lo mismo sin tantas vueltas.

Comment: Asi es hermano esto es lo bonito que hay muchas formas de hacerlo el filter  es mas enfocado en el manejo de informacion de archivos dataframe